# How to accesss php associative array values?

Tags: php, json

My var_dump $data looks something like this. I am looping through user names and I need to get the value "username1"

$key returns an integer when I loop through $key=>$value.

```
array(1) {
  ["username1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["enum"]=>;
    array(1) {
      [1]=>;
      array(1) {
        ["label"]=>;
        bool(true)
        }
      }
    ["total"]=>;
    int(20)
  }
```

Edit 1: here's my code
assignment

```
foreach($keys as $key){
            $this->data[] = array_fill_keys($keys,$this->getData($key, date('Y')));
}
```

function getData

```
private function getData($key, $year)
    {
        return isset($this->datas[$key][$year]) ? $this->datas[$key][$year] : array();
    }
```

loop to access value

```
foreach($this->data as $kpi=>$value)
{
            var_dump($kpi);
}
```

Solution :

The problem was here

```
$this->data[] = array_fill_keys($keys,$this->getData($key, date('Y')));
```

The data[] array had integer indexes.

iterating through $this->data[1] gives me the key values.

But However, I feel there is a better way to handle this, Could someone please help me to improve this?

Comment: `$key` shouldn't return an integer for an associative array, it should return the string key. You must be looping over the wrong array. Post your code.

Comment: @Barmar , You were right! The array was nested within the int index. So effectively I was looping through the wrong array (or the wrong level in the array)

Answer (score -2):

sorry for writing comment as an answer earlier. Question was not clear.

Basically the type of associative array you trying to do should look like something like this.

‘$keys = array( "username1" =>array( “enum” => (int)3, “label” => true, “total => (int)20 ));’

So the value of “username1” is going to be arrays of “enum” and  “label”

Lastly the as $key array must be written like ‘$key[‘enum’]
$key[‘label’] $key[‘total’] right after the foreach command

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Asking questions is not answering, please improve your answer. I do NOT want to downvote it.